# Which module is best in meteor to apply the security and data intigrity checks on backend with schema?

Tags: meteor

While adding allow/deny rules ensures that only authorized users can edit a document from the client, adding a schema ensures that only acceptable properties and values can be set within that document from the client. Thus, client side inserts and updates can be allowed without compromising security or data integrity.
Schema validation for all inserts and updates is reactive, allowing you to easily display customizable validation error messages to the user without any event handling.

Comment: You lack a clear question in the question body. Also, asking "Which triceratops is best" is off-topic for SO as it tends to attract opinionated answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use collection2 package(A Meteor package that allows you to attach a schema to a Mongo.Collection. Automatically validates against that schema when inserting and updating from client or server code).

Please follow the below link....
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2

Comment: This is **not** an answer and should have instead been posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the simple-schema package documentation for a list of all the available schema rules and validation methods.

Use the MyCollection.simpleSchema() method to access the attached SimpleSchema instance for a Mongo.Collection instance. For example:

check(doc, MyCollection.simpleSchema());

I think this will also applicable at this place and also very much easy and simple to impliment.

Link is refered below:-

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema